# _blank target form submition in loop in chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, html, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a requirement to open multiple windows with most of same but few different values (Chrome n IE is not executing below code as expected).
Here is piece of **javascript** code in my way..

```
function test(){
   for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
      var eForm = document.forms[0];
      eForm.action = "demo_form.asp?targetNum="+i;
      eForm.target = "_blank";
      eForm.submit();
   }
}
```

And this is my html form..

```
<form method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="test();">
</form>
```

This code is running perfectly with firefox and as expected opening 3 tabs. But with chrome & IE it opens only one window (not sure if it is overriding previous windows in same tab). In chrome it shows window with last `targetNum` as `2` and in IE it shows first `targetNum` i.e. `0`.

My aim is to achieve the behavior of firefox with chrome and IE as well i.e. to open multiple windows with respective form values.

Somewhere while looking for the soln I found a forum post which says to add `onsubmit="this.action=this.action + '1';"` under my form tag, tried the same but it didn't worked.

**P.S.:** Cant use window.open as I am populating values from java bean and that get override with last window opened.

Comment: Working in chrome and as well IE, the same code you posted

Comment: Can you please share your chrome version? Mine is 31.0.1650.63m

Comment: @vikas, Is it opening 3 tabs on your chrome n ie?

Comment: Chrome just blocking more then one opening pop-up. Cause your form with target="_blank" - it's a just new pop-up window. So it opens only one of them. In my Chomium I have first one opened and Chromium shows me notice that this site has blocked pop-up windows.

Answer (score 1):

not sure you are looking this kind of solution. i have modified your script like below. Hope it will help you.

```
 var i=0;
function test(){
   var eForm = document.forms[0];
   eForm.action = "demo_form.asp?targetNum="+i;
   eForm.target = "_blank";
    if(i!=3)
    {
     setTimeout(function(){ i++; eForm.submit(); test(); },100); 
    }
}
```